# Computing $E(W)$ if $F_W(w)=1-e^{-\lambda(w-t)}-\lambda(w-t)e^{w-t}$ for $ t\le w$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, expectation

Let $W$ a random variable such that:

$$F_W(w)=1-e^{-\lambda(w-t)}-\lambda(w-t)e^{w-t}      \text{       for    } t\le w$$

Compute $E[W]$

I think that it's correct to use the right tail formula for expectation:

$$E[W]=\int_t^\infty(1-F_W(w))dw$$
computing that integral I obtain that $E[W]=\frac{2}{\lambda}$, but the answer given is $E[W]=t+\frac{2}{\lambda}$

It's incorrect to use the right tail formula in this case?

Comment: Please, check $F_W(w)$ above it seems there is a typo.

Comment: The correct formula for any nonnegative random variable $W$ is $$E[W]=\int_0^\infty(1-F_W(w))dw$$ In your case $F_W(w)=0$ for every $w$ in $(0,t)$ hence this adds $$\int_0^t(1-F_W(w))dw=t$$ to your formula, which confirms the solution you were given.